# /n in string should not be stored in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, certificate, quarkus, java-11

In our application we have a certificate which we put in our application.properties like blow

```
cert=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMISDNAJJBSJdsa\nSBAKskjacssack\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now we retrieve this property as a String and store it in dynamodb but when we store this it still persisting this \n which we don't need. Plus we can't change the data member type from String to any other type.

currently in dyanmodb

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMISDNAJJBSJdsa\nSBAKskjacssack\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE--
```

expected entry in dynamodb

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MISDNAJJBSJdsa
SBAKskjacssack
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE--
```

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB will save exactly what you provide it, you're saving a String with `\n` included, so DynamoDB saves it as is.

DynamoDB is a database, not a from end rendering tool, it has no notion of what `\n` means. You could consider saving each line as an element in a list, and then render those on from the list when you require it.